# Jekyll permalink doesn't work

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to add a new page to my jekyll site and I declare the permalink like this:

```
permalink: /new-page/
```

But the new page ends up in mydomain.com/pages/new-page/ instead of mydomain.com/new-page/

This worked before, it must have happened after some jekyll update.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: that should work, I am on the latest and do that all the time. Can you post the entire frontmatter? you sure you have the opening  and closing ---? are you testing this locally or through GH?

Comment: Any code repository url can help.

Answer (score 1):

You must do it like this:

```
---
layout: default
title: Your website name
permalink: /about/
---
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the problem. I had forgot the closing markdown dashes (---) after the permalink.